# "cp --parents" equivalent on Mac

Tags: macos, bash-scripting, cp

The topic explains it -- basically I have a bash script used on a Linux system and a Windows system with Cygwin where the following command works perfectly:

```
cp --parents
```

However, running this same command on Mac in terminal gives the following error:

```
cp: illegal option -- -
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

I am using the command in this context copying a select list of files into an output directory and retaining their directory structure:

```
cp --parents foo/gen1.file foo/bar/gen2.file foo/gen3.bar bar/foo/bar.file ~/my-output/
```

What can I do to get the `cp --parents` behavior?

Comment: If you are copying the whole directory structure from foo/ on down, then `rsync -av foo ~/my-output/` would work for you.  You can choose specific files with filter rules; but, that is starting to veer away from your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to synthesize this command on MAC by using the Rsync parameter -R to copy the relative directory structure of the file I was copying.

Syntax:

```
rsync -R <list of files to copy> <target dir>
```

Usage:

```
rsync -R foo/gen1.file foo/bar/gen2.file foo/gen3.bar bar/foo/bar.file ~/my-output/
```

This gets the same result though I'm sure there's probably a bit of overhead added from using RSYNC rather than CP

Answer (score 1):

`--parents` is probably a non-POSIX behavior specific to GNU `cp`, whereas the BSD-derived `cp` in OS X doesn't have it.

You can probably get the functionality you want by installing the GNU `cp` on your Mac and using that. It's probably part of a GNU package called `fileutils`, and you can probably install it with Homebrew, MacPorts, or Fink.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `basename` ? If so:

```
$ for i in `ls foo/gen1.file foo/bar/gen2.file foo/gen3.bar bar/foo/bar.file`; do cp $i ~/my-output/`basename $i`; done
```

Comment: This solution needs `dirname` or parameter expansion instead of `basename`. I was able to make this solution work by changing it to `for i in foo/gen1.file foo/bar/gen2.file foo/gen3.bar bar/foo/bar.file; do mkdir -p "${HOME-}"/my-output/"${i%/*}" && cp "${i-}" "${HOME-}"/my-output/"${i-}"; done` where the `mkdir -p ... ${i%/*}` (alternatively `mkdir -p "${HOME-}"/my-output/"$(dirname "${i-}")"`) creates parent directories in `~/my-output` for each file before copying them there.